# Navbar causing scrollbar

Tags: html, css

My navbar seems to be making extra space at the bottom causing a vertical scrollbar to appear

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOzEMo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculators</title>
    <link href="calculator.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>


<header>
    <h1>
    <center><img src="https://i.imgur.com/YtL5Qyq.jpg" style="width:220px; height:175px;"></center>
    </h1>
    <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href='home.html'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='program.html'>Programs</a></li>
                <li><a href='training.html'>Training Submissions</a></li>
                <li><a href='calculator.html'>Calculators</a></li>
                <li><a href='http://uspa.net/' target="_blank">USPA</a></li>
                <li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wilks.js"></script>


    <div class='calc-bg'>
        <div class="w-calc">
            <select id="sex">
                <option value="male">male</option>
                <option value="female">female</option>
            </select>
            <select id="units">
                <option value="kg">kg</option>
                <option value="lb">lb</option>
            </select>
            <p>Body Weight: <input id="weight" type="number"></p>
            <p>Total: <input id="total" type="number"></p>
            <input type="button" onClick="computeWilks()" value="Calculate"/>
            <h2 id="wilks"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body> 


<footer>
        <div id="social">
            <a class="instagram" href="http://instagram.com/ucipowerlifting"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/e7fsd60.jpg" width="60" height="60"></a>
            <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/788049644580281/?ref=br_rs"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/812KuNA.jpg" width="60" height="60"></a>
            <a class="contact" href='contact.html'><font color="white">Contact</font></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

</html>

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Patua+One|Roboto|Open+Sans|Roboto+Slab|Oswald);

* { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

h1 {
    background-color: black;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}


.nav {
    width: auto;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #595959;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.nav > li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14.08%;
    max-width: 100%;

}


.nav > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
}


.nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}


.calc-bg{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
}

.w-calc {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(255, 210, 0);
    text-align: right;
    background-color: white;
}


h2 {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 25px;
}

footer {
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Patua One';
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-top: white;
    margin-top: 3%;
}


#social {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3%;
}


.facebook {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}


.instagram {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-right: 3%;
}


.contact {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 3%;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The footer should be at the bottom of the page, but there is a white space the same size as the nav bar at the top (not shown). I believe it has something to do with the header being outside of the body tag, but I'm not certain.

I'm new to HTML/CSS so sorry if the code is a mess and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All html should be inside the body.

Comment: I've just moved all html inside the body, but I'm still getting the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar is the result of your `.calc-bg` element having a `height: 100%` property. Remove this and the scrollbar will go away.

Comment: I'm trying to use .calc-bg to make the left half the page colored, rather than having the whole middle part of the website white.

Comment: I'm trying to make something along the lines of this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOzEMo

Comment: This is a different problem. You could hack it by changing the `.calc-bg` `height` property to `calc(100% - 230px);` which will remove the `<header>` element's height (which is basically what you are after), but in general you are excessively using `absolute` positioning which is bad practice. But, that's not the scope of your question...

Comment: Thanks! I've been self-learning HTML/CSS so I'll take a closer look at absolute positioning.